# Grails:Use Controller and GSP

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp, join

```
class Candidate  {
    String username;
    static HasMany=[applications:Application]
}

class Vote {
   String name;
   Date firstdate;
   Date enddate ;
   static HAsMany=[applications:Application]
}


  class Application {
        Date datedemand;
        Candidate candidate; 
        Vote vote;
   static belongsTo = [candidate:Candidate,vote:Vote]
    }
```

I want to see the candidates in a vote from Application in View .
I started ​​the following attempt, and I remain blocked :
if I click on a vote it shows the candidates this vote

```
def candidatsGrpByVte(){
    def results = Application.withCriteria {
    createAlias("vote", "vote")
        projections {
            groupProperty("vote.name") 
        }
    }
}

    def candidatesByVName(def vname){
        def results= Application.createCriteria().list() {
            createAlias("candidate","candidatAlias")
            createAlias("vote","voteAlias")
            eq('voteAlias.name',vname)
            projections {
               property('candidatAlias.username')
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: And make sure your real code is `static hasMany=`

Comment: yes the code is correct